# What is the check "if var:" actually doing in the background in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, comparison

I kind of know the difference between `var == None` and `var is None`, however my question is about the following condition check:

```
if var:
  action
```

Is the above equivalent to:

```
if not var == None:
  action
```

or is it equivalent to:

```
if var is not None:
  action
```

Or does it depend on what is the current type of the "var" variable, how it performs the check?

Or does it have a completely different mechanic in the background?

Coming from that as a follow up what would happen if the value of "var" is actually 0 and it's of type float or int and I use the `if var:` construct?

Any insights about the inner workings of Python3 are much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: [This is the relevant section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Importantly: "By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object."